# Why isn't Zion broadcasting a movie like "The Matrix" inside the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix, parallel-universe

Is there a reason why inhabitants of Zion choose not to broadcast a documentary of their reality all over the Matrix either via hacked broadcasting channels or movie/internet outlets?

A potential purpose would be sparking thought that nagged the trapped into realizing there is something wrong with their world. Consequently, (nearly) all of them could want to be freed due to a rejection of the system.

Even if they couldn't be freed due to old-age rejection, strategically it could still cause a catastrophic shutdown of the machine's main energy supply.

**Are there any in-universe reasons for Zion not attempting this strategy?**

Comment: I like where your mind is at.

Comment: They would start wondering what would happen if the people in the movie saw the movie.

Comment: Morpheus (and several of the Matrix comics) make it clear that most minds that are presented with "the choice" on a conscious level tend to "pop", e.g. die.

Comment: Billions of people already think something is wrong with the world and there are countless religions to help them get over it.  Anyone inclined to believe some cock and bull story about everything being a simulation run on some computer would have been sucked into a tested, tried and true organized religion long before.  It wouldn't even be a stretch to roll the Matrix myth right into an existing religion.  The real world is a virtual hell compared to life in the Matrix.  Or at least Purgatory.

Comment: Simple.  What happened when you saw it?

Comment: (meta) hm. not possible to answer to on-hold questions?

Comment: Ask the answer to yourself. Experiments confirm that we live in The Matrix. Yet, you think it's fictional after watching the movie.

Comment: Maybe they were!?

Comment: Had Neo seen "The Matrix" in the Matrix, he would have never followed the white rabbit recognizing it to be just a prank.

Comment: This is now answerable, based on the new film. Apparently merely being *told* about the Matrix is fine, if it's in the context of a fake news story or video game (or presumably, a movie)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The greater majority of the people in the simulation would probably just ignore any such broadcast, or dismiss it as some crazy fiction.

To [quote Morpheus](http://thematrixtruth.remoteviewinglight.com/html/transcript-of-the-matrix-5.html):

> The Matrix is a system, Neo. That system is our enemy. But when you're inside, you look around. What do you see. Business men, teachers, lawyers, carpenters. The very minds of the people we are trying to save. But until we do, these people are still a part of that system, and that makes them our enemy. **You have to understand, most of these people are not ready to be unplugged. And many of them are so inert, so hopelessly dependent on the system that they will fight to protect it.**
>   <sub>*emphasis mine*</sub>

Most of the people inside the simulation have become so dependent upon the Matrix and its rules that to even *think* their entire world was based on a lie would be too much for them.

Comment: ― To paraphrase Gone with the Wind; “I'll think of it tomorrow. I can stand it then. Tomorrow, I'll think of some way to ignore it. After all, tomorrow is another day.”

Comment: Much like how we ignore the reality shown by the movie...

Comment: I think that should be [inured](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/the-matrix-script-screenplay-pdf-download/).

Answer (score 9):

This question was very specifically addressed in the Matrix Comic "[Get it?](http://web.archive.org/web/20040806104840/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/baggep1.html)" in which a normal human (inside the Matrix) is shown a copy of the film "**The Matrix**".

Although it is described as a 'comedic spoof', it's also a strong indication of the "*inert, ...hopelessly dependent*" attitude that Morpheus suggests that most humans display;

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Johnny comes out of the movie theatre after watching the Matrix with
>   two friends. While the two friends thought of it as the "best movie
>   ever", Johhny does not get the movie. Amazed at that, the three go
>   into the Tin Hat Tavern, where James tries tries to explain the basic
>   gist of the movie, with the other friend tell him not to bother.
>   Giving up, Johnny leave the bar, thanking his two friends for the
>   beer. As Johnny leaves through the door, his friends, as well as
>   everyone else reveal their agent earpieces and the two friends,
>   actually Agent Lewis and Agent Davies, do not believe him a him to be
>   a problem, with Lewis saying that "the fewer humans who comprehend
>   whats really going on, the fewer we must destroy!"